# Both of console.log and functions.logger(firebase-functions) don't show logs in Firebase pubsub(schedule) function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm new to Firebase and now I'm trying to make a schedule function.

So I tried this one to see if the schedule function works.

```
exports.testSchedule = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('*/1 * * * *') // every one minute.
  .timeZone('America/New_York')
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    console.log("Hello world")
    functions.logger.info("Hello world");
  });
```

And I started Firebase emulator

```
firebase emulators:start
```

It seems like works properly.
[screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fZhm.png)

Then I waited more than 10 mins but I could not see any log from console.log() or logger.info()
Please let me know what's wrong with my code.
Thank you.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Also please copy the entire output of the Firebase CLI into your question, not just what you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Emulator currently does not support scheduled functions. I think the problem here is that the function `testSchedule` is not being triggered, and not `console.log` and `functions.logger.info` not working.

You should be able to verify this using the code snippet below:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions/v1");

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    functions.logger.info("Hello world");
    return res.send("Hello world")
})
```

Calling the function endpoint on "http://127.0.0.1:5001/PROJECT_ID/us-central1/helloWorld" should show the log message:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-helloWorld"
>  {"severity":"INFO","message":"Hello world"}
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-helloWorld" in 3.4885ms
```

Alternatively, if you want to run the scheduled function, you can use the `firebase functions:shell` command then invoke the function there. i.e

```
firebase > testSchedule()
```

Logs would show:

```
'Successfully invoked function.'
firebase > >  Hello world
>  {"severity":"INFO","message":"Hello world"}
```